# PHP - Sessões e cookies

Tags: php, cookies

Eu tenho uma página `login.php` que depois de ser preenchida vai para o `processa.php` e depois entra com a sessão e cookie:

```
$cookie_name = "Administrador";
$cookie_value = $id;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (3600), "/");
$_SESSION['user'] = $id;
header("Refresh: 0; url=MENU/menu.php");
```

E na página `login.php`, eu queria fazer algo do tipo, se o utilizador que já tenha feito login, queira voltar no site, e se direcione para o login, o login verifica se a sessão ainda existe e manda ele de volta para o `menu.php`. Eu fiz desta maneira mas parece não funcionar:

```
<? 
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        setcookie("Administrador");
        session_destroy();
    }else
    {
        $user = $_SESSION['user'];
        header("MENU/menu.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Tente assim: `header("Location: MENU/menu.php");`

Comment: Usei sempre header com refresh que até esqueci que o location existia! até fiquei envergonhado! Obrigado por me lembrar ivan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função header do PHP

```
header("Location: http://www.seusite.com.br");
```

> Mais detalhes aqui: [função header php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php)